# How can I resolve this Xcode OptimizationLevelError error while previewing simple swiftui code in canvas?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I've been successful using SwiftUI for a few months with very little Xcode experience.  I'm trying to add some simple help screens that I would like to preview in the SwiftUI canvas.  However, I'm receiving the following error:

OptimizationLevelError: not building -Onone

The message is shown when pressing the "diagnostics" button.  Problem persists after pressing "try again" button.

```
Xcode: Version 11.3 (11C29)
Catalina: 10.15.2 (19C57)
```

The code could not be simpler:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HelpSortView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You can sort the list by Name, Sail Number, Class, or Favorites.")
                .lineLimit(10)
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image("help-sort")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HelpSortView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HelpSortView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had my Xcode scheme, Build Configuration set to Release instead of debug.  In Xcode, select Product, Scheme, Edit Scheme, Run (on left side), Info tab, Build Configuration, set drop-down to Debug.